# Como realizar uma query dentro de um nodeList?

Tags: javascript, dom

Usando JavaScript puro, realizei a seguinte query:

```
let elems = document.querySelectorAll("a.menu-item, span.menu-item");
```

Após usar os itens desse `nodeList`, eu precisei usar outros elementos que possuíam as tags anteriores e mais uma genérica (como, por exemplo, `.nova-classe`). Como eu realizo uma query para pegar os itens com essa classe de dentro desse nodeList sem ter que refazer a query inteira e sem usar `JQuery`?

O que desejo é, mais ou menos, o funcionamento do pseudocódigo abaixo:

```
var elem = documento.pesquisa("a.menu-item, span.menu-item")

// uso do nodeList "elem"

elem = elem.pesquisa(".nova-classe")

// uso do nodeList "elem"

elem = elem.pesquisa(".outros-elementos")

// uso do nodeList "elem"
```

Comment: Você quer verificar se os elementos dentro do NodeList tem a classe nova ou pegar os **filhos** dos elementos do seu NodeList?

Comment: verificar quais elementos do NodeList tem a classe nova

Comment: mas a parte dos filhos também é interessante, já existem respostas pra essa pergunta?

Comment: Para a parte dos filhos você poderia executar o `querySelectorAll` em cada item do `NodeList`. Esse método pode ser usado em qualquer elemento, filtrando apenas os filhos dele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para verificar quais elementos do seu `NodeList` contém a nova classe você pode usar dois métodos: verificar a lista de classes de cada elemento, ou testar pelo seletor.

Com a lista de classes (`classList`):

```
var elem = [...document.querySelectorAll("a.menu-item, span.menu-item")].filter((item) => {
    return item.classList.contains("nova-classe");
});
```

Com o seletor:

```
var elem = [...document.querySelectorAll("a.menu-item, span.menu-item")].filter((item) => {
    return item.matches(".nova-classe");
});
```

A vantagem do seletor é que você pode testar tanto classes como atributos ou tags, o método `matches` faz um teste baseado no query selector. Ambos os métodos retornam um Array com os elementos do seu `NodeList` que contém as classes que você pesquisou.

A sintaxe `[...document.querySelector]` é necessária porque a classe `NodeList` não possui o método `filter`, então a convertemos para um Array.

Answer (score 1):

O `document.querySelectorAll` resulta em um nodeList de todos os elementos condizentes com o seletor utilizado, caso você queria garantir que alguns itens não entrem na sua nodeList, você pode aumentar o nível de especificação utilizando o `:not()`, no seu exemplo:

`document.querySelectorAll("a.menu-item:not('.nova-classe'):not('.outros-elementos'), span.menu-item:not('.nova-classe'):not('.outros-elementos')")`.

Caso você queria apenas saber se eles existem no seu nodeList basta utilizar um forEach e observar para cada um dos casos.

```
var elementList = documento.pesquisa("a.menu-item, span.menu-item");
elementList.forEach(element => {
    // se possui uma id
    console.log(element.id == 'novo-id');
    // se possui uma classe
    console.log(element.classList.contains('.nova-classe'));
    // se possui uma atributo
    console.log(element.hasAttribute('value'));
    // se possui uma atributo e valor
    console.log(element.getAttribute('value') == 10);
})
```